# Entity Framework - Error while trying to call parametrized function

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, oracle11g

I've mapped some function that is being used as a wrapper for the one of the Oracle functions (I really need to call that Oracle function from my LINQ).

**My mapping looks like (Storage Model):**

```
<Function Name="RunTranslate" IsComposable="false" BuiltIn="false">
    <CommandText>
        SELECT Translate(@DataToTranslate using char_cs) AS ResultData FROM dual
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="DataToTranslate" Type="char" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

**And:**

```
<FunctionImport Name="OracleTranslate" ReturnType="Collection(String)">
    <Parameter Name="DataToTranslate" Mode="In" Type="String" />
</FunctionImport>
```

**I try to use it from the code this way:**

```
using (var context = new TestEntities())
{
    ....

    var result = from myData in context.OracleTranslate("test")
                 select myData;    // Error ORA-00936!
    ....
}
```

I tried to use Entity Framework Profiler (EFProf) to see the query that is actually being sent to the DB. Intercepted query is the next:

```
SELECT Translate('test' /*@DataToTranslate*/ using char_cs) AS ResultData FROM dual
```

(looks fine)

But my application stops with the next error:
**ORA-00936: missing expression**

If I copy-paste the intercepted query into the VS2010's Server Explorer Query Window - it works! DB returns correct data to me!

So, where the problem can be? What is the difference between the code and the query window in my case? I thought they use the same provider, etc...

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**:

I've just used standard Inet-sniffer to check the real data that is being sent over the sockets and Internet when I run my query.

And it's not the same with the first one! It's exactly my source SQL query:

**SELECT Translate(@DataToTranslate using char_cs) AS ResultData FROM dual**

It seems, that parameter is not recognized, but why?

Comment: Write it as an answer once you can, please.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, I hope this info will help someone:

DataToTranslate parameter should be mapped with the colon symbol (":DataToTranslate"), not "@".

Another important experience (as to me): Entity Framework Profiler (EFProf) shows something that it wants, not the real data - much better to use TCP-sniffers like Wireshark to see that data.